# Confirm Password Validation Not Working

Tags: magento2, javascript, password, password-recovery

I have an issue with the confirmation password validation on creating the account and reset password pages and showing the following error although the passwords match?

> Please enter the same value again.

Any ideas on how to resolve the issues? I haven't got any JS console errors.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, I believe it is because I added modal login/register form to all pages in my theme. The register modal has a field with `id="password"` I think the validator is checking this value rather than the desired input.

I have not fixed/tested this theory yet but it would make sense. Double check to ensure you do not have an additional `id="password"` on these pages

Answer (score 0):

Should check your template again.

1) Make sure we didn't need change id of password element. Because the confirmation password based on it:

vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml

```
data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}"
```

2) Should try to debug the Js: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/. My Magento version is 2.2.0 and the Js validation is `jquery.validate.js`. In your Browser (I used Chrome), open Sources Tab and debug.

[image]

Comment: The ID of the password input matches what the data-validate is referencing, and jquery.validate.js is getting added to the page but still doesn't seem to be working. Do I need to add this to my require config file?

Comment: Did you override this file `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml`?

Comment: I haven't updated any of the phtml files to do with this :/

Comment: Do you use a Magento fresh install? I tested on Magento 2.2.0 version.